# Terminal stuck on sudo indefinitely

Tags: terminal, mojave, mac-pro, sudo

I'm on the latest version of Mojave 10.14.4 (18E226), Darwin 18.5.0 on a 2012 Mac Pro. The system has become totally unusable for any sudo commands. It gets stuck indefinitely whenever I fire a sudo. Moreover, remote screen sharing has also stopped working. It was working fine before the restart. I even turned off the firewall after restarting, but remote screen sharing still doesn't work. SSH works though.

I came across this bug on Mac OS 10.12.4 on multiple forums. Most solutions involve modifying the sudoers file but that involved firing a sudo command and "waiting it out", but I've waited hours without any success!

Not sure if this is connected, but I recently removed administrator privileges for a user (from System Preferences > Users & Groups). The system asked for a restart for changes to take effect. I restarted and this bug kicked in.

Any leads?

Comment: If you are using Terminal go to the Shell menu item and click. Near the botom of the pane that opens are option for Reset and Hard Reset. I would try those and see if either one works.

Comment: Try this - https://ilyabirman.net/meanwhile/all/fix-sudo-on-a-mac/

Comment: Sadly, I don't have access to the physical machine. I can only log in remotely via SSH for now. And remote access to the GUI isn't working...

Comment: Think that'll require some level of a admin to assist w/ this further.

Comment: Yeah. I'm working to find someone who has physical plus admin access to the machine. It's weird though. I've never seen such weird behaviour from MacOS in the past. I've been using it for a good 8-9 years now...